# checked changed event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to fire the checkbox checkedchanged event but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something here in the following code. I think I have fulfilled all the necessary conditions. So what can be wrong?

```
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelApprove" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelApproved" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Green"></asp:Label>
          <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBoxApprove" Text="Approve?" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxApprove_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True"/>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="CheckBoxApprove" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
         </Triggers>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**edit**
the code in C#

```
          protected void CheckBoxApprove_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox CheckBoxApprove = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)CheckBoxApprove.Parent.Parent.Parent;
    HiddenField HiddenFieldAnswerId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("HiddenFieldAnswerId");
    HiddenField HiddenFieldExpertId = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("HiddenFieldExpertId");
    Label LabelApproved = (Label)row.FindControl("LabelApproved");
    UpdatePanel UpdatePanelApprove =(UpdatePanel) row.FindControl("UpdatePanelApprove");

    int AnswerSubjectId = AnswerDataAccess.GetSubjectIdForAnswer(Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldAnswerId.Value));
    if (!AnswerDataAccess.CheckAnswerApprovalStatus(Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldAnswerId.Value)))
    {
        if (AnswerDataAccess.ApproveAnswer(Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldAnswerId.Value)))
        {
            if (HiddenFieldExpertId.Value != Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString())
            {
                NotificationsAccess.InsertNotification(AnswerSubjectId, null, Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldAnswerId.Value), null, "Approved your answer", new Guid(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()), new Guid(HiddenFieldExpertId.Value));
            }
            LabelApproved.Text = "Approved";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (AnswerDataAccess.DisapproveAnswer(Convert.ToInt32(HiddenFieldAnswerId.Value)))
        {
            LabelApproved.Text = "";

        }
    }
    UpdatePanelApprove.Update();
}
```

pageload code

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
    HtmlGenericControl Tabs = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("divTabs");
    Tabs.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "block";
    Tabs.Style["border"] = "1px solid #eee";
    Tabs.InnerText = "some text";
    Tabs.Style["font-size"] = "10px";
    if(!IsPostBack )
    {
     DataTable UserS=ProfileDataAccess.GetUserS    (Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
     DropDownListS.DataSource=UserS;
     DropDownListS.DataValueField ="SId";
     DropDownListS.DataTextField="Sub";
     DropDownListS.DataBind();
     ListItem item= new ListItem("Select-s", "0");
     item.Selected = true;
     DropDownListS.Items.Add(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: What can that be? The id is correct I think.

Comment: I copied the whole code of yours, it runs perfect. :|, What is the problem/error? Event not firing? Label not updating? Or what? May be you are updating some content which is not in _this_ updatepanel?

Comment: what happens after you check the CheckBox

Comment: did you set any break point and debugged?

Comment: Check if any js error occured (CTRL+Shift+J). Set a break point in the event handler and see if code reaches there.

Comment: You don't need `Triggers` here because trigger is inside the update panel

Comment: Yes I have set the breakpoint in the start of the code. it is not reached

Comment: Well, your handler does nothing, so nothing happens, right?

Comment: @Damith yes I know that about the triggers but this was desperate attempt to make it work.

Comment: I removed the code.. for bravity.

Comment: where is your updatepanel in any other control

Comment: @mshsayem check the code now

Comment: @AmitSingh the Update panel is inside the itemtemplate of the gridview row.

Comment: where you binding the gride view row must b in page load right ?

Comment: @AmitSingh Sorry it is not in pageload event...

Comment: show page load event code

Comment: if it not in page load than when you binding you gridview code

Comment: declaratively or when the answer is posted (in buttonclick event)

Comment: yuor event is not firing at alll right

Comment: no nothing is happening!

Comment: nothing is happening means yuor checkbox doesnt make post back right

Comment: beginRequesthandler and endRequestHandler in asp.net ajax is firing correctly..

Comment: Did you check the error console of the browser? Is there any error? I think there might be a casting error. I made a small case and it was `(GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent` (4 parents, you are using 3 parents). Also the trigger is necessary for autopostback events

Comment: @mshsayem his event is nof firing at all...it doesnt reach there

Comment: but he says "asp.net ajax is firing correctly"

Comment: Yes @mshsayem yes you are right this was present too I added one more level of parent and it was fixed :) . but still the break point is not reached now..

Comment: @mshsayem i also doesnt understand at all why its not firing

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="QuestionDisplay.aspx.cs" Inherits="QuestionDisplay"
    Title="Untitled Page" %>
This is the page's header..

Comment: Actually I am unlucky that is why it is not firing.. :(

Comment: is your page load event fired..put break poit and check//it

Comment: Sorry I was out for launch... ok.. I restarted the visual studio and it started to work... Thanks for help.. it was nice

Answer (score 1):

Het Try this property `EnableViewState="true"` in checkbox control.